# How to make a connection to the Server from UWP application using Mobile?

Tags: c#, web-services, mobile, service, win-universal-app

I am building an `UWP application` which is supporting for both Desktop and mobile Devices.

My Application is interacting with **services** which are deployed in some where else in the network. Using below code for checking the *status of the services*.

```
 if (strIpAddress != string.Empty && strPortNumber != string.Empty)
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var stream = client.GetStreamAsync(string.Format(ServiceUrl.SERVICE_URL, strIpAddress, strPortNumber)).Result)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I am accessing through *Desktop, its working fine*. But when I am trying to connect from Mobile, getting the following exception:

> The text associated with this error code could not be found. A connection with the server could not be established

I have enabled all features in **capabilities**, still getting the same exception.

Please give your suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: If the server is in the same network, enable the `Private Network` capabilities in the `Package.appxmanifest`. If this is not the issue, can you try with other servers, e.g., `http://example.com` and see if there is any difference.

Comment: What you said is right we need to enable Private Network ... I forgot about Net Connection . I need Internet connection for connecting to services.Now I am able to access services from Mobile also. But your point is also a valid one ... Thanks a lot @kiewic

Comment: @kiewic please write your comment as answer, I almost missed it, but it was the right answer for me too